# How to create a map with Java stream API using a value outside the stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I want to init a `Map<String, BigDecimal>` and want to always put the same `BigDecimal` value from outside of the stream.

```
BigDecimal samePrice;
Set<String> set;

set.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), samePrice));
```

However Java complains as follows:

> The method toMap(Function, Function) in the type Collectors is not applicable for the arguments
>   (Function, BigDecimal)

Why can't I use the BigDecimal from outside? If I write:

```
set.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), new BigDecimal()));
```

it would work, but that's of course not what I want.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The second argument (like the first one) of [`toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) is a function that takes the stream element and returns the value of the map.

In this case, you want to ignore it so you can have:

```
set.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), e -> samePrice));
```

Note that your second attempt wouldn't work for the same reason.

Answer (score 9):

`Collectors#toMap` expects two `Functions`

```
set.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), x -> samePrice));
```

You can find nearly the same example within the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-)

> ```
>  Map<Student, Double> studentToGPA
>      students.stream().collect(toMap(Functions.identity(),
>                                      student -> computeGPA(student)));
> ```

Answer (score 7):

As already said in the other answers, you need to specify a function which maps each element to the fixed value like `element -> samePrice`.

As an addition, if you want to specifically fill a `ConcurrentHashMap`, there is a neat feature that doesn’t need a stream operation at all:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String,BigDecimal> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
map.keySet(samePrice).addAll(set);
```

Unfortunately, there is no such operation for arbitrary `Map`s.