# Streaming two lists into a map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to learn java 8 streams and i'm having trouble converting the following code into streams

```
parents = new ArrayList<Integer>() ...
children = new ArrayList<Intger>() ...
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> result = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
for (Integer parentId : parents) {
    result.put(parentId, new ArrayList<Integer>(children));
}
return result;
```

Something like this doesn't work

```
return parents.stream()
              .collect(toMap(p -> p, children));
```

Tunaki provided the link that lead to the answer: [How to create a map with Java stream API using a value outside the stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36356041/how-to-create-a-map-with-java-stream-api-using-a-value-outside-the-stream)

The answer:

```
return parents.stream()
              .collect(toMap(Function.identity(), e -> new ArrayList<>(children)));
```

The problem was that I needed to pass an element to the value function, even if I don't use it and capture from outside instead. I was trying to give it a function that accepted nothing.

Comment: Try: `return parents.stream().collect(toMap(Functions.identity(), () -> children));` Read more about `toMap` in [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-)

Comment: But why do you want to map all these parent IDs to the same list?

Comment: Why it doesn't work? what's wrong with it?

Comment: It seems your *starting* data should be the Map. How else can you associate children with a parent?

Comment: If you really want to have the same value for each key (which is kind of weird), refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36356041/how-to-create-a-map-with-java-stream-api-using-a-value-outside-the-stream

Comment: Oh wow, didn't catch that. Yeah, I don't want each key to point to the same List in memory. Edited original question accordingly.

Comment: @alfasin that didn't work. Won't compile, eclipse says this:
The method toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K>, Function<? super T,? extends U>) in the type Collectors is not applicable for the arguments (Function<Object,Object>, () -> {})

Comment: seems that passing ` () -> {}` won't work because `toMap` expects the second argument to be a function that takes an argument and returns a value. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tunaki provided the link that lead to the answer: [How to create a map with Java stream API using a value outside the stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36356041/how-to-create-a-map-with-java-stream-api-using-a-value-outside-the-stream)

The answer:

```
return parents.stream()
              .collect(toMap(Function.identity(), e -> new ArrayList<>(children)));
```

The problem was that I needed to pass an element to the value function, even if I don't use it and capture from outside instead. I was trying to give it a function that accepted nothing.